# how to add a specific property to Widget without wrapping it as a child using extension in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, extension-methods

I am using extension to give padding to the widget

**Extension:**

```
extension Hello on Widget {
    paddingAll(int x) {
       return Container(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(x.toDouble()),
         child: this,
       );
 }
```

Use Case :

```
Container( child: Text("Hello")).paddingAll(40);
```

But this evaluates to :

```
 return Container(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
   child: Container(
       child: Text("Hello"),
   ));
```

What I want is :

```
return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Text("Hello"),
    );
```

How to achieve this via `extension function`? If any further more simplified method ,please suggest the same .

Comment: what problem facing now?

Comment: I want to write an extension which evaluates to `what i want is ` code. What i have now is the above one

Comment: you can simply check over it inside the extension method, if(this == Container)...

Comment: See `what this evaluates to` code section and `what i want` code section . You'll understand the question

Comment: I dont want to wrap `widget` inside `widget` , I just want to change the existing `widget` using extension . This is the intension of the question

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
extension Hello on Widget {
  paddingAll(int x) {
  return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(x.toDouble()),
    child: this
);
}
}
```

then you should call like this

```
Container(color: Colors.red, child:Text("Padding").paddingAll(20))
Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("Normal")).paddingAll(20)
```

this is the difference

[image]

Comment: I take it as you didn't understand the question completely,  I want the changes to happen in the same hierarchy not as a child . `child:this` makes it a child

Comment: Thank you for explaining the answer in detail. This completely works fine. But i want to do using the Container example itself . Because padding has a `Padding` widget whereas the `margin` doesn't have it's own widget . So at that time solution can be possible by only changing the present `Container` because there is no option of wrapping that in some other widget

Comment: I want a solution which doesn't wrap in any widget . Instead directly alter . Because if i chain it `Container(...).paddingAll(20).paddingAll(20).paddingAll(20)` it will be 3 nest deep . Which i dont want to happen. I want to change at that level not inside . How can it be possible

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this

```
extension Hello on Container { // <==== change Widget to Container
  paddingAll(int x) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(x.toDouble()),
      child: child, // <==== here
    );
  }
}
```

**this** ===> **Container**

**child** ====> child of **Container** ====> **Text**